# Postgres/base in Ubuntu using Symlink Error

Tags: postgresql, symlink

I try to symlink Postgres/base to another drive because the base drive is out of space.

I followed this:

"Stop the server.

Copy the datadir while retaining permissions - use cp -aRv.

Then (easiest, as it avoids the need to modify initscripts) just move the old datadir aside and symlink the old path to the new location."

Unfortunately, it did not work. When I typed psql, the error says "cannot find base"

I already checked the postgres access authority for both locations of base (old and news).

Any suggestions? Maybe symlink cannot work for this case?

I did go the folder and do a ls -l. The link is correct.It says: "base -> /host/base". I also restart the server after creating the symlink. It does not work. If I typed "psql", the error message says: "cannot find base/11991"

Comment: I suggest to give some more details, for example the exact error message, and the given commands. Thus you will be able to get much better answers.

Comment: Did you start the server (after creating the symlink) ?

Comment: Maybe you can also post a ls -l for your folders to see whether the links are correct.

Comment: Hi, I did go the folder and do a ls -l. The link is correct.It says: "base -> /host/base". I also restart the server after creating the symlink. It does not work. If I typed "psql", the error message says: "cannot find base/11991"